# Powershell Send-MailMessage fails authentication on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to send some emails on a pipeline in `Azure Devops` with the following `Powershell` task:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |    
      $username = "$(emailUsername)"
      $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$(emailPassword)" -AsPlainText -Force

      $credentials = [PSCredential]::New($username, $password)

      $sendMailParams = @{
          SMTPServer  = 'smtp.office365.com'
          Port        = 587
          UseSsl      = $false
          Credential  = $credentials
          From        = $username
          To          = '${{ parameters.recipientsAddresses }}'
          Subject     = '${{ parameters.mailSubject }}'
          Body        = '${{ parameters.mailBody }}'
      }

      $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

      Send-MailMessage @sendMailParams -Encoding $encoding
```

The `PowerShell` script works just fine running locally on my machine, yet when I try to run it on my pipeline it fails with the following message:

```
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server 
response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [<MAIL_SERVER>.outlook.com]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have MS agent or self-hosted agent?

Comment: MS agent, currently running it on `ubuntu-latest`

Comment: So I guess you need open ports or access in your SMTP to the agent ip

Answer (score 0):

There can be different reasons for this:

1. The `From` address as `emailAddress`, which is not a proper email address. For `Office 365` the From needs to be a real address on the `Office 365` system. You can validate that if you hardcode your email address as the From and your `Office 365` password.
2. Make sure that `$credentials` you set are correct.

Comment: I really doubt any of these reasons, as this script works just fine when run locally.

Comment: Can you try using different values for these once?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both locally and on the pipeline, got the same results.